# por que sale este error [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to?

Tags: java, jsf, sql, jpa

tengo una lista a la cual le paso un find y a la hora de pintar esa lista en consola, sale lo siguiente:

PRUEBA NUEVA LISTA 
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@5e45ebba, [Ljava.lang.Object;@64e65a0b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@4d96ba80,n]

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```html
private List<RegistroAcceso> listRegistroAcceso;
 

listRegistroAcceso = registroAccesoService.findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1(cvePersona);
 
        System.out.println("PRUEBA NUEVA LISTA \n" +listRegistroAcceso);
```

Porque me pinta eso y no mis datos?

luego quiero tratar de mostrar un atributo de esa lista

```html
System.out.println("PRUEBA BIOMETRICO" +listRegistroAcceso.get(0).getNreaderidn());
```

y sale el error: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to mx.gob.sre.sicoin.domain.RegistroAcceso

porque sale ese error?

Asi tengo mi service

```
public List<RegistroAcceso> findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1 (Integer cveUser);
```

y la implementacion

```
 @Transactional
public List<RegistroAcceso> findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1(Integer cveUser) {
    return new java.util.ArrayList<RegistroAcceso>(registroAccesoDAO.findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1(cveUser));
}
```

el DAO

```
public Set<RegistroAcceso>  findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1(Integer cveUser) throws DataAccessException;
```

Y la implementacion

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public Set<RegistroAcceso> findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1(Integer cveUser) throws DataAccessException {
    Query query = createNamedQuery("findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1", -1, -1, cveUser);
    return new LinkedHashSet<RegistroAcceso>(query.getResultList());
}
```

el query que contiene el find es

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1", query = "select  CASE  WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52730 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52731 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52734 THEN 'TRIANGULAR' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52735 THEN 'TRIANGULAR' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52737 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52738 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52739 THEN 'JUAREZ' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52762 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52768 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' WHEN myRegistroAcceso.nreaderidn = 52769 THEN 'INDEPENDENCIA' ELSE 'NADA'  END , CASE WHEN myRegistroAcceso.neventidn IN(55,44,43) THEN 'EXITOSO' ELSE 'ERRONEO' END, TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') + (myRegistroAcceso.ndatetime/24/60/60) AS FEC_EVENTO  FROM RegistroAcceso myRegistroAcceso WHERE myRegistroAcceso.nuserid =?1  ORDER BY myRegistroAcceso.ndatetime ASC"),
```

Comment: Lo que tienes es un mensaje porque ha saltado una excepción. Las excepciones llevan asociado un `stacktrace` que te indica en que punto te salta la excepción. Pon el stacktrace en la pregunta, e indica en qué línea de tu código salta la excepción.

Comment: el error ssale en esta parte, System.out.println("PRUEBA BIOMETRICO" +listRegistroAcceso.get(0).getNreaderidn());

Comment: cual es el contenido de la *named query* `findRegistroAccesoByNuserid1` ?

Comment: @Klaimmore, ya edite la pregunta con el contenido

Comment: no estas seleccionando la entidad RegistroAcceso

Comment: @Klaimmore   es correcto, lo que pasa es que si lo pongo despues del select, ya no levanta la aplicacion, ya que esta mal la sintaxis, ya lo intente probar

Comment: Creo que tienes que leer la respuesta de @SJuan76 aplica para tu caso

Comment: @Klaimmore, hay forma de hacer ese proceso del query con java?

Comment: No hay forma de mantener ese query tal y como esta, o lo adaptas para retornar entidades RegistroAcceso, o lo adaptas para retornar instancias de otro objeto (con new en el query)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74516/discussion-between-root93-and-klaimmore).